# why is it possible to access private data members when passing an object to a method?

Tags: c++, oop, methods

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class distance {
private :
   int feet;
   int inches;
public :
   void setfeet(int x) { feet = x; }
   int getfeet(void) { return feet; }
   void setinches(int y) { inches = y; }
   int getinches(void) { return inches; }
   distance add(distance temp) {
       distance result(0, 0);
       result.feet = feet + temp.feet;
       result.inches = inches + temp.inches;
       return result;
 }
    distance(int ft, int in) : feet(ft), inches(in) {}

};

int main(void)
{
    distance a(5, 6);
    distance b(3, 4);
    distance sum(a.add(b));
    cout << sum.getfeet() <<"\n";
    cout << sum.getinches() << "\n";
    return 0;

}
```

In this code sample, I can access **private data members** of result object which is created inside the method **add** and I can also access the **private data member** of object temp which is a parameter in the method **add** using the **dot(.)** operator
how is that possible?

Comment: `private` applies to class as a whole, not to single object (instance of the class). See the linked duplicates.

Comment: Instances of the same type simply have access to each other's private members. It makes sense when you consider things like copy/move operations.

Comment: A member function of a class is allowed access to the private data members of *all* objects of that class type, not only the `this` that it is called on.

Comment: The intention of the access specifiers (`public`, `protected`, `private`) is to provide encapsulation. It is _not_ for security or privacy.

Comment: @AndyG or any binary operator